# Is NXP's PCA9548A compatible with TI's TCA9548A?

Tags: i2c, multiplexer, component-selection

I am using TI's TCA9548A in my Projects, but I would like to know if I can substitute it with PCA9548A from NXP.

By comparing the datasheets this seems to be indeed the case, but I am wondering why they have different names.

By the way, is it really like this regarding these logic chips, that same numbers under different manufacturers mean same functionality? Like the in the case of 74HC595 for example?

Comment: Sounds more like a distinction between "Philips" and "TI" than anything else.

Comment: "...regarding these logic chips, that same numbers under different manufacturers mean same functionality? Like the in the case of 74HC595 for example?" Functionality: **YES** it will be the same, other parameters: **maybe** see the datasheet ! But the 74HCXXX range is made by many manufacturers and they are all called 74HCXXX. The TCA9548/PCA9548 are not "standard" parts like the 74HCXXX range !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Texas Instruments](http://www.ti.com/product/PCA9548A) say: -

> Recommended alternative parts
>
> TCA9548A  - The device has the SAME FUNCTIONALITY and PINOUT as the compared device but is NOT an exact equivalent.   TCA9548A is an
>   enhanced version of the PCA9548A with an extended supply voltage range
>   and performance enhancements related to Power-On Reset.

Now in this statement they are comparing their TCA9548A with their PCA9548A so there could be some doubt about this applying the NXP part.

Comment: That's actually a good point... after comparing the two parts' supply voltage range TCA from TI accepts 1.65V...5.5V whereas PCA from NXP doesn't seem to go so low as 1.65V although it is not so clear.

Also the Vpor has different values. But the differences are very small.